Geeting error while add phone number on registration page
Custom/CustomerAttribute/Setup/Patch/Data/AddPhoneAttribute.php
<?php
namespace Custom\CustomerAttribute\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
* Class AddPhoneAttribute
* @package Magenest\CustomerAttribute\Setup\Patch\Data
*/
class AddPhoneAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{
    /**
    * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
    */
   private $moduleDataSetup;
   /**
    * @var EavSetupFactory
    */
   private $eavSetupFactory;
   /**
    * @var ProductCollectionFactory
    */
   private $productCollectionFactory;
   /**
    * @var LoggerInterface
    */
   private $logger;
   /**
    * @var Config
    */
   private $eavConfig;
   /**
    * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute
    */
   private $attributeResource;

   /**
    * AddPhoneAttribute constructor.
    * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    * @param Config $eavConfig
    * @param LoggerInterface $logger
    * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute $attributeResource
    */
   public function __construct(
       EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
       Config $eavConfig,
       LoggerInterface $logger,
       \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute $attributeResource,
       \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
   ) {
       $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
       $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
       $this->logger = $logger;
       $this->attributeResource = $attributeResource;
       $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public function apply()
   {
       $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
       $this->addPhoneAttribute();
       $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
   }

   /**
    * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException
    * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
    * @throws \Zend_Validate_Exception
    */
   public function addPhoneAttribute()
   {
       $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();


       $eavSetup->addAttribute(
           \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
           'phone_number',
           [
               'type' => 'varchar',
               'label' => 'Phone Number',
               'input' => 'text',
               'value' => '',
               'required' => 1,
               'visible' => 1,
               'user_defined' => 1,
               'sort_order' => 999,
               'position' => 999,
               'system' => 0
           ]
       );

       $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(Customer::ENTITY);
       $attributeGroupId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId(Customer::ENTITY);

       $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'phone_number');
       $attribute->setData('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);
       $attribute->setData('attribute_group_id', $attributeGroupId);

       $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
           'adminhtml_customer',
       ]);

       $this->attributeResource->save($attribute);
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public static function getDependencies()
   {
       return [];
   }

   /**
    *
    */
   public function revert()
   {
   }

   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public function getAliases()
   {
       return [];
   }
}

Custom/CustomerAttribute/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        
         <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
           <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                  name="phone_number"
                  template="Custom_CustomerAttribute::extra_field.phtml"/>
       </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

app/code/Custom/CustomerAttribute/view/frontend/templates/extra_field.phtml
<div class="field phone_number required">
   <label class="label" for="phone_number">
       <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Phone number')) ?></span>
   </label>
   <div class="control">
       <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Phone number')) ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
   </div>
</div>

I'm using Magento 2.4,6
I used the above code to add the phone number to the registration page. phone number is showing but getting the error "Phone Number" is a required value. while creating an account.

I request that everyone please guide me on this issue. Thank you in advance..

Do you want phone # not to be required?

Phone should required.

I use this code and it worked fine
Custom\CustomerAttribute\Setup\Patch\Data\AddPhoneNumberCustomerAttribute
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Custom\CustomerAttribute\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;

class AddPhoneNumberCustomerAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{

    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetup
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    /**
     * @var SetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param SetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        SetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
        
        /** @var $attributeSet Set */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
        
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'phone_number',
            [
                'label' => 'Phone Number',
                'input' => 'text',
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'source' => '',
                'required' => true,
                'position' => 333,
                'visible' => true,
                'system' => false,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );
        
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'phone_number');
        $attribute>setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address','adminhtml_customer']
        );
        $attribute->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId
        
        ]);
        $attribute->save();

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'phone_number');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
        
        ];
    }
}

Custom\CustomerAttribute\etc\extension_attributes.xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
        <attribute code="phone_number" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>

Custom/CustomerAttribute/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        
         <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
           <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                  name="phone_number"
                  template="Custom_CustomerAttribute::extra_field.phtml"/>
       </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

Custom/CustomerAttribute/view/frontend/templates/extra_field.phtml
<div class="field phone_number required">
   <label class="label" for="phone_number">
       <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Phone number')) ?></span>
   </label>
   <div class="control">
       <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Phone number')) ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
   </div>
</div>

result is phone # saved

in database

